# Need help creating Mongodb collection for the following

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a web application for objective questions answers with solutions. I am using Mongodb and i have to create the collections for the following with relationship.

```
Classes (like lkg, ukg … )
-- Subjects (like Maths, English …)
---- Lessons (like Lesson 1, Lesson 2 …)
------ Chapters (like Chapter 1A, Chapter 1B …)
-------- Questions (Q1, Q2 …. With correct answer and its description)
```

I have thought the following but i'm not able to understand the relationship of my Lessons collection. So i really need help to create my collection with relationship. One can suggest different solution from mine.

```
"Classes": [
    {"id": 01, "name": "Class 1", "slug": "class-1"},
    {"id": 02, "name": "Class 2", "slug": "class-2"},
    .......
]

"Subjects": [
    {"id": 01, "name": "Math", "slug": "math"},
    {"id": 02, "name": "English", "slug": "english"},
    .......
]

"lessons": [
    {
    "name": "Lesson 1",
    "slug": "lesson-1",
    "class_id": 01,
    "subject_id": 01,
    "chapters": [
        {
        "name": "Chapter 1A",
        "slug": "chapter-1a",
        "questions":[
            {
                "que": "Question 1 here?", 
                "choices": ["A": "ans 1", "B": "ans 2", "C": "ans 3", "D": "ans 4"],
                "answer": "A",
                "description": "Solution description will go here....."
            },
            {
                "que": "Question 2 here?", 
                "choices": ["A": "ans 1", "B": "ans 2", "C": "ans 3", "D": "ans 4"],
                "answer": "B",
                "description": "Solution description will go here....."
            },
            ............
            ............
            ]
        },
        {
        "name": "Chapter 1B",
        "slug": "chapter-1b",
        "questions":[
            {
                "que": "Question 1 here?", 
                "choices": ["A": "ans 1", "B": "ans 2", "C": "ans 3", "D": "ans 4"],
                "answer": "A",
                "description": "Solution description will go here....."
            },
            {
                "que": "Question 2 here?", 
                "choices": ["A": "ans 1", "B": "ans 2", "C": "ans 3", "D": "ans 4"],
                "answer": "B",
                "description": "Solution description will go here....."
            },
            ............
            ............
            ]
        },
        ...................
        ...................
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "Lesson 2",
    "slug": "lesson-2",
    "class_id": 02,
    "subject_id": 02,
    "chapters": [
        {
        "name": "Chapter 1A",
        "slug": "cahpter-1a",
        "questions": [
            {
                "question": "Question 1 here?", 
                "choices": [A: "ans 1", B: "ans 2", C: "ans 3", D: "ans 4"],
                "answer": "A",
                "description": "Solution description will go here....."
            },
            {
                "question": "Question 2 here?", 
                "choices": [A: "ans 1", B: "ans 2", C: "ans 3", D: "ans 4"],
                "answer": "B",
                "description": "Solution description will go here....."
            },
            ............
            ............
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Chapter 1B",
            "slug": "chapter-1b",
            "questions":[
                {
                    "question": "Question 1 here?", 
                    "choices": [A: "ans 1", B: "ans 2", C: "ans 3", D: "ans 4"],
                    "answer": "A",
                    "description": "Solution description will go here....."
                },
                {
                    "question": "Question 2 here?", 
                    "choices": [A: "ans 1", B: "ans 2", C: "ans 3", D: "ans 4"],
                    "answer": "B",
                    "description": "Solution description will go here....."
                },
                ............
                ............
                ]
            },
            ...................
            ...................
    ]
    },
    ....................
    .......................
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would not implemented this kind of data structure. This is what one would do in SQL par lands.

Instead, flatten out the structure, and make sure your endpoints include what your views need and nothing else nested bellow.

Something like:

```
"lessons": {
  "lesson_id_1": {
    "name": "Lesson 1",
    "slug": "lesson-1",
    "class": "Class 1",
    "subject": "Math",
    "chapters": [
      "Chapter 1A"
    ]
  }
},
"questions": {
  "lesson_id_1": {
    "Chapter 1A": {
      "slug": "chapter-1a",
      "questions": [{
        "que": "Question 1 here?", 
        "choices": ["A": "ans 1", "B": "ans 2", "C": "ans 3", "D": "ans 4"],
        "answer": "A",
        "description": "Solution description will go here....."
      },{
        "que": "Question 2 here?", 
        "choices": ["A": "ans 1", "B": "ans 2", "C": "ans 3", "D": "ans 4"],
        "answer": "B",
        "description": "Solution description will go here....."
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

You can get all of your lesson data in one go with `/lessons/lesson_id_1`

Get lessons 1, chapter 1A questions: `/questions/lesson_id_1/Chapter 1A/`

--

What your trying to do is SQL. You need to shift your paradigm, and ask the questions, what data do I really need where?

Comment: again the structure I propose is just one flatten version of the relational model you've shown, the actual model that fits your use case will entirely depend upon it.